# Change line in <script> tag only for IE

Tags: internet-explorer, conditional-comments

I want to change a line inside a script tag only for IE.

The line is:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {  
    $("body").niceScroll({
      mousescrollstep: false,
    });
  });
</script>
```

So, I went with conditional comments like:

```
<!--[if lte IE 9>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {  
        $("body").niceScroll({
          mousescrollstep: 32,
        });
      });
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

...but it doesn't work.

Comment: `gte IE 9` is targeting versions of IE that are greater than or equal to 9 -- eg 9, 10, 11... It's unclear what you're actually trying to do. What versions of IE are you trying to target? What version are you testing on? And what does "it doesn't work" mean here? Also conditional comments were removed in IE 10.

Comment: @roddyofthefrozenpeas sorry, i wanted to write lte (lower than or equal):D I am testing on IE8 right now. I am targeting all IE version that accept conditional comments. And by it doesn't work I mean to say that mousescrollstep: false disables scroll in IE and for it to work I need to replace it with 32, if it did work that the scroll would've worked which it doesn/t.